# After putting Node 5, npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

After installing Node 5, I am getting an error in the terminal everytime I run whatever with npm

> npm -v: 2.14.12

and here I am trying to update npm to the last version:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-MarceloRS:promo-auto-loans-1 Marcelo$ sudo npm install npm -g
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "npm" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #1: Expected string but got object
npm ERR! typeerror     at markDeps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:87:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:35
npm ERR! typeerror     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:11
npm ERR! typeerror     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! typeerror     at asyncMap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:51:8)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR! typeerror     at LOOP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
npm ERR! typeerror     at chain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at recalculateMetadata (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:112:3)
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Marcelo/Documents/Projects/BankOfAmericaApps/promo-auto-loans-1/npm-debug.log
```

and I get the same error of `npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE` whatever I run npm xxxx.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try to remove node, then npm: `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and `rm /usr/local/bin/npm`, and `rm ~/.npmrc`, This will completely remove npm. And install node from `brew install node`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on my linux machine. I upgraded my node from 5.0.0 to 5.1.0 and now works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

same issue happend to me.

first i deleted the node_modules folder and then the package-lock.json file but the problem still persisted.

when i looked at my package.json file for some irregularities i noticed a dependency that was just an empty string -
something like: "dependencies": {..., "": "^5.3.1" ,...}.

once i deleted that empty dependency, npm was running again.

hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted both the `node_modules` folder as well as the `package-lock.json` file and then rerun module installation with npm.
`rm -rf node_modules` & then `rm -rf package-lock.json` and finally `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I manually added the package name (@materia-ui/core) in the package.json and ran `npm install` once in the root directory and once in subdirectory (We have a mono-repo with lerna) and it worked. I have no idea how and why.

Don't forget to remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`